# Did I miss anything on my playthrough of A Dark Room?

Tags: a-dark-room

I've finished A Dark Room, but I feel like I rushed it or something and even missed out on a great revelation.

When I discovered the ship, I showed the woman and she gave me her locket and disappeared. At this point in the game, I was mining iron, coal, and steel, and had recently built an armory, with all 80 "slaves" working on something. The newest weapon was a rifle, though I'd discovered a carbine but could not buy it.

I spent most of my time using the locket to lead me to alien alloy.

> I'd assumed it meant foreign alloy, until the creators had to tell me I'm an alien.

I upgraded my ship to 12 and 12, and flew off, finally ending the game and returning to square one..
Are there other things I should have discovered? It feels so uneventful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have built all of the building/items and found the locket, etc, i'd say there isn't much left for you to get (Other than finding the old man in the swamp possibly for more "lore", and a perk if you give him a charm).

If you are looking for another challenge, you could try to get the alternate ending by **building no huts**.

At this point though, it sounds like you've hit just about everything